# Cyclic graph not displayed correctly in visNetwork when using hierarchical layout?

Tags: r, visnetwork

When I use `visLayout(hierarchical = TRUE)` I get the following picture, which I think is wrong:

[image]

With `visLayout(hierarchical = FALSE)` I get the (correct) picture:

[image]

Is that a bug or do I miss something? Reproducible example:

```
nodes <- structure(list(id = 1:4, label = c("node1", "node2", "node3", "node4"),
                        value = c(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3),
                        title = c("node1", "node2", "node3", "node4")),
                   .Names = c("id", "label", "value", "title"),
                   row.names = c(NA, -4L),
                   class = "data.frame")

edges <- structure(list(from = 1:4,
                        to = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L),
                        arrows = c("to", "to", "to", "to")),
                   .Names = c("from", "to", "arrows"),
                   row.names = c(NA, -4L),
                   class = "data.frame")

visNetwork(nodes, edges, height = "100%", width = "100%") %>%
  visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE) %>%
  visLayout(hierarchical = TRUE) %>%
  visInteraction(navigationButtons = TRUE)

visNetwork(nodes, edges, height = "100%", width = "100%") %>%
  visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE) %>%
  visInteraction(navigationButtons = TRUE)
```

Comment: @symbolrush I just got the same idea! That is the solution. If you like, add an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a layouting issue:
The edge from node 4 to 1 is plotted underneath the nodes. Therefore it seems as if there's a doublesided arrow between nodes 1 and 2..

That's why in the circular layout everything is as you expect.